# How to kill all processes with the same name using OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, shell, kill-process

Getting the following output from running this:

```
ps aux | grep Python
```

Output:

```
user_name  84487   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  Z    12:15PM   0:00.00 (Python)
user_name  84535   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  Z    12:16PM   0:00.00 (Python)
```

I want to terminate all Python processes currently running on a machine....

Answer (score 126, accepted):

use [pkill](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pkill.htm), with the `-f` option.

```
pkill -f python
```

If you don't have `pkill` pre-installed (some osx's don't...), try [proctools](http://proctools.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Actually, some of the answers will quietly fail, not killing the processes.
Namely, in case-sensitive environments (like Mac, Unix, etc) you should take care of process name -> "Python" instead of "python" and in addition, you might need "sudo".

So, here are the options:
`sudo killall Python`
or
`sudo pkill -f Python`

Answer (score 37):

If you don't have `pkill`, you can try this:

```
ps aux | grep python | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

If that gives you the PIDs you want to kill, join that up with the kill command like this

```
kill $(ps aux | grep python | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

That says... kill all the PIDs that result from the command in parentheses.

Comment: don't need grep here: `ps aux | awk '/python/ {print $2}' | xargs kill`

Comment: Glenn: That is more elegant than my answer, please go ahead and suggest it yourself and grab the points - you won't offend me. I'll vote for you! Also, please tell me how I can refer to your name (which contains a space) using the @ mechanism. Thank you.

Comment: I think if you just use "@glenn", that will notify me. Usually in a comment, you can type "@gl" and my name will be auto-suggested in which case you can hit Tab to complete. However if you're replying to the previous comment, the system figures out who you're replying to. It all pretty much just works. Regarding the points, my code was just a refinement of yours, it's not a substantially new answer.

Comment: kill -9 $(ps aux | grep python | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}') worked for me

Comment: Brilliant, saved me from restart. Because I had processes spawning all the time in my terminal I got the message that "fork: Resource temporarily unavailable". I tried to kill processes in Activity Monitor but that was too slow. So I quit some programs that were running - Mail, Safari - and very quickly switched to terminal and ran the ps aux.... command - BAM. 1,300 processes killed!

Comment: Note that the "grep"-based solution provided by Mark is cross-platform. The "awk"-based solution suggested by Glenn does nothing on OS X. The only change I made to this answer is to "grep -i python" so it catches both Python and python.

Answer (score 9):

```
killall python
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: did not work for me - killall simply didn't work as advertised, it killed nothing. OS X 10.13.3

Comment: @n13, for OS X: killall Python

Answer (score 3):

@shx2: Thanks for the trick! Here are the steps to make it work:

Step1:

```
cd /usr/bin
```

Step2:

```
touch "pkill"
```

Step3: With textEditor of your choice open the file you just created: /usr/bin/pkill (do it with sudo or be Admin). Copy/paste this and save:

```
for X in `ps acx | grep -i $1 | awk {'print $1'}`; do
  kill $X;
done
```

Step3: Set file attribute

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/pkill
```

Now you ready to terminate any process using a simple syntax:

For example, to terminate all Python processes open a shell and type:

```
pkill Python
```

All python processes should be gone by now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, some of the answers will quietly fail, not killing the processes.
Namely, in case-sensitive environments (like Mac, Unix, etc) you should take care of process name -> "Python" instead of "python" and in addition, you might need "sudo".

So, here are the options:
`sudo killall Python`
or
`sudo pkill -f Python`

Answer (score 0):

```
pgrep python | xargs sudo kill -9
```