# Killing multiple Mac OS processes dynamically in one command?

Tags: linux, macos

I have this issue where sometimes .Net Core crashes when I run the debugger in VS Code, and I'm unable to restart the debugger. Even if I quit out of VS Code and go back in, the processes are still open. Rather than restart the machine, I can kill each process manually, but sometimes there are a whole bunch of them, and it gets pretty tedious. For example:

```
$ ps -eaf | grep dotnet | grep -v grep
16528 ??         0:02.65 /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /Users/ceti-alpha-v/Documents/NGRM/application/NGRM.Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/NGRM.Web.dll
16530 ??         0:02.75 /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /Users/ceti-alpha-v/Documents/NGRM/application/NGRM.Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/NGRM.Web.dll
16532 ??         0:02.85 /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.403/Roslyn/bincore/VBCSCompiler.dll

$ kill 16528 16530 16532
```

I'd like to delete the processes automatically with a single command, but I'm not sure how to pipe each PID to `kill`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334761/osx-terminal-how-to-kill-all-processes-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xargs` like this

```
ps -eaf | grep dotnet | grep -v "grep" |  awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

or if you want to just kill all `dotnet` processes

```
killall dotnet
```

Comment: Both `pkill` and `killall` worked for me. But good to know the awk way of doing it, too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use command Substitution

```
kill $(ps -eaf | grep dotnet | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: You forgot to extract the process id from ps output

Comment: thanks for mentioning @JanGassen